# Correct movement to exact position when using floats

Tags: c++, sdl

In my pathfinding game, I have the following code:

```
void Dot::move( Tile *tiles[], float timeStep )
{
        mVelX = (points[currentPoint].x * TILE_WIDTH)
                + (TILE_WIDTH / 2 - DOT_WIDTH / 2)- mBox.x;
        mVelY = (points[currentPoint].y * TILE_HEIGHT)
                + (TILE_HEIGHT / 2 - DOT_HEIGHT / 2) - mBox.y;

        mBox.x += mVelX * DOT_VEL * timeStep;
        mBox.y += mVelY * DOT_VEL * timeStep;
}
```

`mBox` is the position.  `points` refers to the solution of a pathfinder. The dot has no problem moving from tile to tile, but it's always "off center".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jszZ.png

Some solutions I've considered:

1. Create a tiny bounding box in the center of each tile. This however sometimes "misses" the collision.
2. Use an epsilon value. Unfortunately this leads to trial and error and imprecise results.

The other issue is with easing (for example adding friction). The dot will "slide" for way longer than it needs to until it reaches the center. This results in awkward movements.

Comment: what type are TILE_WIDTH and TILE_HEIGHT?

Comment: @OMGtechy Integers. So is `DOT_VEL`.

Comment: Try using `static_cast<float>(insert_each_thing_here)` on TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, DOT_WIDTH and DOT_HEIGHT, as well as changing 2 to 2.0f.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make the circle's "position" the center of the circle instead of the edge, you should be fine.  If you are keeping the right edge as a "position", then when you center it or whatever, you should offset it to the right by the radius by the circle.

I have answered this question to the best of my ability, however it is hard to give a complete, accurate, and correct answer with the code provided.